# Send data to a Modal using Bootstrap and PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

```
<td>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' title='Give feedback'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' ></span>
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea  name="txtFeedback"cols = "50" rows = "10" class="form-control" placeholder="Please keep your feedback encouraging "></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <form id= "id" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" style="background-color=436786" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When the button defined in the php is clicked i want it to submit a value to the modal. How do I do that? Without using javascript or ajax. Just php and bootstrap

Comment: the statement is ambiguous. please refine it "submit a value to the modal"

Comment: In PHP `<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn' value='$story_id' name='btnViewComments' title='View comments'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span></button></td>` you can do something like this and once button is clicked the value of the button is submitted. I would like to do the very same thing but with a modal

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: why you dont need the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your button as a submit button of a form:

```
<td><form action="yourphpscript.php" method="post"><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' title='Give feedback'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' ></span></button></form></td>
```